# Wordpress: PHP form redirecting to index on submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

In a Wordpress theme. I am submitting a contact form. The form action is to `<?php the_permalink() ?>`.

Var dump of `var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` returns `string(28) /folder/index.php`.

My form is:

```html
<form action="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="form-row__name" placeholder="name" />
                <input type="email" name="email" id="form-row__email" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <textarea name="message" id="form-row__message" placeholder="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>
```

I cant seem to get it to submit successfully, whichever php code I use.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with your form? Please explain the problem you are having, as it isn't clear for what you've told us so far ("*I cant seem to get it to submit successfully*" doesn't give us anything to go on). The form being submitted to `index.php` is not necessarily an issue, because themes can send all requests to that to control the behaviour of your pages.

Comment: The exact issue you are having isn't clear, but looking at your code I can see that you're using `the_permalink` incorrectly so that's going to cause problems. I've added and answer that will fix this.

Comment: You need to update your question with full details of exactly what is going wrong. As I said, "not working" doesn't tell us anything :) The 404 error is important information, so please edit your question with this and any other details you have so we can help solve the right problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the whole part, where you use the inputs of the form, clean the data and use a Send Mail function to actualy do the "contact form" make work.

I would suggest using the plugin "Contact Form 7" for wordpress, which is highly adjustable and has a lot of spam protection and safety issues, which you only can reproduce with an really high effort, if you try to build it by your own. So have a look: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/ You can simply put the shortcode of your form inside of your theme file, that's it.

---

If you want to make it by your own I can give you some directions. First of all it is better practice to create a custom plugin for this. So you should think about putting it not directly inside of your theme file. Maybe you want to use the form somewhere else, and that way you would have to copy everything over again. Creating a custom plugin is the way to go.

Using FTP, go to your `wp-content/plugins/` folder and create a new folder called `qa_contactform`. I choose the name because of your user name. Take what you like to. Inside of this folder, create a php file called the same `qa_contactform.php`.

Open and edit this PHP file and put the following code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: QA contact form plugin
Description: QATester19 Contact form
Version: 1.0
Author: QATester19
*/
function contactform_code() {
    echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<div class="form-row">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="form-row__name" placeholder="name" name="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="50" />';
    echo '<input type="email" id="form-row__email" placeholder="email" name="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="50" />';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-row">';
    echo '<textarea rows="8" id="form-row__message" placeholder="message" name="message">' . ( isset( $_POST["message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="form-row">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function send_the_mail() {

    // send mail when submit button is clicked
    if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {

        // sanitize values
        $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["name"] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["email"] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["message"] );

        // email address you want the mail to send to
        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // display a success message after sending or error
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thank you for your message.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An error occurred';
        }
    }
}

function contactform_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    send_the_mail();
    contactform_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'show_my_contact_form', 'contactform_shortcode' );

?>
```

If you go to your plugins in the wordpress backend, you can activate it. Your form will now check for pattern in the name, and set the max length of the input. The input will be sanitized for security reasons.

You can show and use this form in your theme files using the shortcode you created in the plugin. Just put this inside of your theme file where you want to display the form:

`<?php echo do_shortcode['show_my_contact_form']; ?>`

Comment: I was using the 'mail()' functionality of php but on submit the form redirected whether is used mail or not so didnt include it in the code above.
Thanks for the advice on plugins. Unfortunately the new plugin returns 404 and redirects to index. Wordpress seems to automatically redirect to index on  submit.

Comment: Where did you put the shortcode in? The action is set to REQUEST_URI so it should send to the same page.

Comment: The shortcode was throwing an error and I put the code in my conrtact page in my theme and put the shortcode in like:
<?php echo do_shortcode('[show_my_contact_form]'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `the_permalink` incorrectly in this line:

```
<form action="<?php echo the_permalink('contact'); ?>" method="post">
```

`the_permalink` takes either a *Post ID* or a *Post Object* as a parameter, but you are passing in a string which I assume is the slug.

If you know the id of the page you want to submit to, then you can pass it in e.g. `the_permalink(123);`. If not, you can get the post object from the slug and pass it into the_permalink as follows:

```
<?php $contact_page_object = get_page_by_path( 'contact' ); ?>
<form action="<?php the_permalink($contact_page_object ); ?>" method="post">
```

**Reference**: [the_permalink documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/)
Also, note that you don't need to use `echo` with `the_permalink` as it outputs the result as standard.

Comment: Either way by using 'get_page_by_path' or actual post ID. Both redirect to 404.

Comment: @QATester19 What is the url in the browser's address bar when you get the 404 error? Also, add this *after* `get_page_by_path` and *before* your `<form>` tag and tell us what you get: `<p> this URL= <?php the_permalink(); ?><br /> Submit to: <?php the_permalink($contact_page_object); ?></p> `

Comment: @QATester19 I've just noticed I'd a typo in my answer - can you update your code to use the form action thats there now, i.e. `<form action="<?php the_permalink($contact_page_object ); ?>" method="post">` and let me know if that worked!

Comment: Interestingly URL shows the same as the ‘contact’ page, but shows the index page strips HTML and css without content.

Comment: I assume you mean the URL in the location bar, and not displayted using the code I asked you to add? As I said earlier, index.php can control all pages so that makes sense. So we've got your redirect working now, but there is an error somewhere else. Idon't understand what do you mean "shows the index page strips HTML and css without content"?

Comment: Even though the url is the contact page, it’s content is not showing the content page. It is showing the index page.

Comment: Well we've fixed the form to go to the right page, so that's a start. I think the problem is with the fields you're submitting, for example "name" is a reserved WP keyword. Change all your input names to something unique e.g. "QATester19_name" and try that. I'd also suggest testing with a simple one-field form and just display the posts values when they are submitted - this eliminates any other complications so you can concentrate on one problem at a time. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thank you soo much. that works but doesnt submit, 'isset($_POST(''submit')' is not true. It correctly returns to the same page. I have since created a working form with contact form 7, ill propbably stick to that for now.

Comment: No problem. I usually avoid plugins but there are a few times I would suggest using one -caching, site migration, Yoast for SEO, ACF for custom fields... and contact forms :)